# C++ delete a node from BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble with my delete function. I don't know what seems to be the problem. Please help me fix this. thank you very much.

```
node* tree_minimum(node *x){

    while(x->left!=NULL){
        x=x->left;
    }
    return x;
}

node* tree_successor(node *x){

    if(x->right!=NULL)
        return tree_minimum(x->right);

    node *y;
    y=new node;
    y=x->parent;

    while(y!=NULL&&x==y->right){
        x=y;
        y=y->parent;
    }
    return y;
}

node* tree_search(node* x,int k){

    if(x==NULL||k==x->key)
        return x;

    if(k<x->key)
        return tree_search(x->left,k);
    else
        return tree_search(x->right,k);
}

node* tree_delete(int b){

    node *y;
    y=new node;
    node *x;
    x=new node;
    node *z;
    z=new node;

    z=tree_search(root,b);

    if(isempty()){
        cout<<"TREE is empty.";
        return NULL;
    }

    if(z->left==NULL||z->right==NULL)
        y=z;
    else
        y=tree_successor(z);

    if(y->left!=NULL)
        x=y->left;
    else
        x=y->right;

    if(x!=NULL)
        x->parent=y->parent;
    if(y->parent==NULL)
        root=x;
    else{

    if(y=y->parent->left)
        y->parent->left=x;
    else
        y->parent->right=x;
    }
    if(y!=z)
        y->key=z->key;

    return y;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: yes. i already tried to fix it. i've been working on it all day. well it actually just has to delete a node from the tree.

Comment: All the other function is fine except the tree_delete :(.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you have a LOT of problems going on here; I think you've misunderstood memory allocation:

```
node *y;
y=new node;
y=x->parent;  // Holy Mackerel!
```

Allocates memory on line two returning an address to the newly allocated memory; the very next line changes the address of y was pointing to (!!) - losing the allocated memory location and creating a memory leak. As these are scattered throughout the code, and you have no `main()` or code showing invocation - there's not much need to go on.

If you are just copying pointers you don't need to perform a dynamic allocatation (i.e. `new` operator).

```
int *x = new int;
int y = 2;
*x = 1;  // Assigns the memory (int) pointed to by x to 1
x = &y;  // Reassigns x to point to y - but without delete the allocated memory's last reference is lost
```

I really recommend you grab a book before going any further.

EDIT:  Also watch out for conditionals like:

```
if (y=y->parent->left)
```

when you most likely meant:

```
if (y == y->parent->left)
```

The logic needs condensing - check out some posts about `BST` on SO, like this one:

[Binary Search Tree Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619427/binary-search-tree-implementation)